# Hibernate JPA Eager fetching not actually doing anything

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, relational-database

I'm trying to use Hibernate's eager fetching to fix an N+1 select problem I am experiencing.

I'm trying to do a EAGER fetch of a one-to-many-to-many relationship:
In my app, each course has some sections, and each section has one or more students (students can be enrolled in multiple sections).

Currently, when I try to fetch all the students in a course, I get an N+1 select issue. I'm fairly certain the N+1 select is not just on the sections but also on the students in each section (my test database has only 4 sections in the course, but each section has 25 students), since I have a fairly large amount of sql statements logged by Hibernate.

I tried making my relationships eager by adding `type = FetchType.EAGER` to my annotations for both `Course.sections (List<Section>)` and `Section.users (List<User>)` but nothing happens.

Here are my entities (heavily simplified):

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Courses")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="courseID")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "course_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int courseID;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="course", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
                type = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @BatchSize(size=100)
    private List<Section> sections;

    public List<User> getEnrolledStudents() {
        return getSections().stream()
                            .flatMap(s -> s.getUsers()
                                           .stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

}
```

and

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sections")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="sectionID")
public class Section {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "section_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int sectionID;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;

    @ManyToMany (cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable (name = "SectionUsers", 
                joinColumns = { @JoinColumn (name = "section_id") },
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name = "user_id")})
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

}
```

My frontend code is essentially doing the following:

```java
Course c = entityManager.find(Course.class, courseID);
for (Section s : c.getSections())
    System.out.println(s.getName());
    for (User u : s.getUsers())
        System.out.println(u.getFullName());
```

Comment: Did you tried with `@Transactional` in your code, where you call it?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I'm not using JTA. But I have ensured to start a transaction beforehand and commit it later

Comment: Do you use spring?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer transaction leads to n+1 select problem instead of `LazyInitializationException`

Comment: @Andronicus What do you mean? I do use transactions, just not JTA

Comment: @ConstantinBeer No, I'm actually using Jersey (JAX-RS)

Answer (score 0):

In `@OneToMany` use `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` instead of `type = FetchType.EAGER`. If you're not certain about n+1 select problem, you can use this [technique](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing/) to prove it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. When I originally copied my code I didn't have that param. I added it in later.

Comment: Then I suggest pasting legitimate code. Have you proven, that there is a n+1 select problem?

Comment: yes. At least 100 SQL statements fly past in the console when I hit my list students endpoint.